# Dominion Card Specific Tags

Tags: discussion, tagging

I'm wondering... Should specific tags should be allowed.  Ie. dominion-card-loan or something like that.

It would generate a lot of extra tags, but I would love to be able to click on a card specific tag and see a list of questions related to that card.

Right now it's not that big of a deal as the number of questions is pretty low, but further on down the road I can see it being useful.

Comment: If you can show evidence that you are unable to find the information you seek with the current search and organization scheme, then a tag is usually justified. However, I think the search features will let you do this just fine. :D

Comment: Not really intersted in searching for something specific.  Just more interested in seeing a list of questions related to a specific cards as needed.  Kinda of a "things to know" before any questions come up in a game.

Comment: what exactly do you want to search for? If you give us some specific examples I'm sure we can help you find what you need with the existing tools. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No -- I think it makes more sense to use search for this, and you *can* scope search to a specific tag, like so:

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdominion%5D+loan

in other words, enter

`[tag] searchterm1 searchterm2`

in the search box in the upper right (or press <kbd>enter</kbd> in the search box to get search help)

Comment: Is there anyway to just search the questions and not the answers?

Comment: @chris search always rolls up to the question anyway, but you can experiment with the advanced search operators that are on the "press enter to get there" page -- http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search